# Clearing browser cache with aurelia bundle revision

Tags: aurelia, browser-cache

I'm getting a **404** on my **app-build.js** bundle whenever I publish (AWS). The browser is referencing the **previous bundle revision** (e.g., dist/app-build-cf4...).

Even with a new bundle revision number and using "System.cacheBust" on the app-build file, it's still holding on to the old rev #.

I have to manually clear the cache to get the site to load.

**Index.cshtml**

```
...
<body aurelia-app="main" class="page">
<div>      
    <div class="splash text-darker-clr" >
        <div class="message">                
            <span>Site</span>
            <br />
            <div id="ajax-loading-screen" data-disable-fade-on-click="0" data-effect="standard" data-method="standard">

                <div class="loading-icon">                        
                    <span class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin spin"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>

    <script>
        var systemLocate = System.locate; System.cacheBust = "?bust=" + Date.now(), System.locate = function (a) { var b = this; return Promise.resolve(systemLocate.call(this, a)).then(function (a) { return a.lastIndexOf("html.js") > -1 ? a : a.lastIndexOf("css.js") > -1 ? a : a + b.cacheBust }) };
        System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    </script>      
</div>
</body>
```

**bundles.js**

```
module.exports = {
"bundles": {
"dist/app-build": {
  "includes": [
    "[**/*.js]",
    "**/*.html!text",
    "**/*.css!text"

  ],
  "options": {
    "inject": true,
    "minify": true,
    "depCache": true,
    "rev": false
  }
},
"dist/aurelia": {
  "includes": [
    "aurelia-framework",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper",
    "aurelia-fetch-client",
    "aurelia-router",
    "aurelia-animator-css",
    "aurelia-templating-binding",
    "aurelia-polyfills",
    "aurelia-templating-resources",
    "aurelia-templating-router",
    "aurelia-loader-default",
    "aurelia-history-browser",
    "aurelia-logging-console",
    "bootstrap",
    "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!text",
    "fetch",
    "jquery",
    "moment",
    "aurelia-bootstrap-datepicker",
    "aurelia-authentication",
    "aurelia-api",
    "aurelia-dialog"
  ],
  "options": {
    "inject": true,
    "minify": true,
    "depCache": false,
    "rev": false
  }
}
}
};
```

[image]

Comment: Does `index.html` on your server reference fresh version of `vendor-bundle.js`?

Comment: I believe so, as System.JS is getting the latest javascript bundle from config.js. I'll edit my question to show my index.html and bundle file